# Partial<T> of object type not assignable to object type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a Model class:

```
export abstract class Model<T = IBaseModel> { ... }
```

where `IBaseModel` is defined as:

```
export interface IBaseModel {
  createdAt: datetime;
  lastUpdated: datetime;
}
```

This abstract base class for Model's then allows for users to assign a "record" property

```
public set record(value: Partial<T>) {
  const now: datetime = moment().toISOString();
  const createdAt: datetime = this.rec('createdAt') || now;
  const timeInfo = { lastUpdated: now, createdAt };
  this._record = { ...value, ...timeInfo };
}
```

For some reason though Typescript is objecting to `value` being treated as an object (which I think it would be ... considering it's defined as a `Partial<T>`. Below is the error ... anyone know what i'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Spreading doesn't work with generics, an example of an issue: [Object Properties Spread with Generic Object Types not allowed](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15792). That are more issues like that, all duplicates of: [Add spread/rest types to support proposed object spread/rest](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727)

Comment: @NitzanTomer the thread you've pointed to seemed to suggest a fix went into 2.3.3 but I'm using 2.4.0 and still getting the error.

Comment: It says `Milestone TypeScript 2.5`.

Comment: Oh I see. I was referring to your first link which talks about 2.3.3 but the second link (which is more directly aimed at my issue) does point to 2.5. Guess it's not in @next yet though as I tried that too yesterday.